# Chrome Extension Check For Clipboard Change

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

Is there any easy way to check whether the clipboard value has changed as part of a chrome extension

Comment: Not currently, see https://crbug.com/677564 and https://developer.chrome.com/apps/clipboard